# How can I use Named Binding in Nodejs while pulling Data from Snowflake?

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have followed the standard Snowflake documentation for setting up a Nodejs backend to connect to Snowflake. I have every set up and queries are working.

My only issue is the seemingly abysmal functionality around binding for queries.

In the documentation a standard example is the following:

```
connection.execute({
  sqlText: 'SELECT c1 FROM (SELECT :1 AS c1 UNION ALL SELECT :2 AS c1) WHERE c1 = :1;',
  binds: [1, 2]
});
```

Is there any way to setup a structure more like the following?

```
connection.execute({
  sqlText: 'SELECT c1 FROM (SELECT :VAR_1 AS c1 UNION ALL SELECT :VAR_2 AS c1) WHERE c1 = :VAR_1;',
  binds: [{ 
    VAR_1: 1,
    VAR_2: 2
    }]
});
```

Just having :1 and :2 inline in the code is borderline useless for readability and would make using Nodejs with Snowflake a bit of a nightmare if you had Stored Procedures / Cursors / Queries with 10+ variables.

I am really hoping I am missing something but so far I have found nothing more on the topic.

Comment: That is indeed not supported as of now and would trigger an error like `Failed to execute statement due to the following error: SQL compilation error:
Unsupported data type 'VARIANT'.`. You can only use in the SQL either the position as in `:1, :2` or `?,?` and then a bind array with each value. You can open a new [Idea](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) as a future improvement.

Comment: Hi @Sergiu is there any plan to develop a better way? We are currently considering a very large switch from Oracle to Snowflake but this will kill that idea.

Comment: Open an Idea using the link I provided and based on the number of votes it will be reviewed by Snowflake's Product Management.